# Delete user from database in 2 days after registration if email is not verified in laravel

Tags: laravel, email, verification

This is my first question on stackoverflow. I want to delete user account after 2 days if the user did not verify his/her email address in laravel and also i want to add countdown timer for that on index page. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome on SO :) But what is your question? Save the datetime where the email was send and create a scheduler job which deletes the users

Comment: Thank you for reply! Yes! But how to delete user based on datetime? Like how to write this in if condition?

Comment: You are the developer so the choise is up to you ;) maybe only within sql. maybe mixed with php.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. That way you can ask more specific questions and we could help you much better.

Answer (score 0):

you may define a scheduled task in your Kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        //your query here
    })->daily();
}
```

read here for more customisation : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#defining-schedules